# Binary Search doesn't work

Tags: c#, binary-search

I have array with int values

```
 int[] myArr = (int[]) alItems.ToArray(typeof (int));

 index = Array.BinarySearch(myArr, searchNumber);
```

When I have searchNumber in myArr it give me negative index, why?

Comment: You do know that a binary search only works on sorted arrays, right?

Comment: This is thoroughly explained [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If binary search returns -1, then the value is not within the array. This can also occur if the array is not sorted (which it needs to be for binary search to work).

Before using binary search you should understand how it works. Take some time to do just a little bit of [research](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976.aspx) before you put it in your code.